# How to ignore few properties in SQL Server JSON value

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a table which has a column with JSON data. Every JSON object in each column has many properties. I have another table which has property name not all but few.

What I need to do is to write a query to select JSON data from table but JSON should not contain properties which are there in the second table. For example, below is the jSON table.

```
Id      Person
1       {FirstName:"test", LastName: "test", Email: "test@test.abc"}
2       {FirstName:"syx", LastName: "ave", Email: "yyeyd@test.abc"}
```

Second table with properties name:

```
ExclusionId   ExcludedProperty
1              Email
```

Query should join these two table and output should be

```
 Id          Person
  1       {FirstName:"test", LastName: "test"}
  2       {FirstName:"syx", LastName: "ave"}
```

Comment: I *assume* you're using SQL Server 2016+?

Comment: Nevermind, the above fails to be parsed by SQL Server as it's not valid JSON: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=332f4056faf682e7c4eb5589971ab034). If you want to be able to parse JSON in SQL, you really need to ensure it's valid.

Comment: @Larnu Yes I am using SQL server 2016. This JSON is just an example I created to explain problem. Assuming JSON is valid what is the right way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fully generic approach with no need for dynamic SQL:

```sql
--a mockup to simulate your issue
--credits to John Cappelletti for the mockup-code
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE (Id INT,Person NVARCHAR(500))
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES 
 (1,'{"FirstName":"test", "LastName": "test", "Email": "test@test.abc"}')
,(2,'{"FirstName":"syx", "LastName": "ave", "Email": "yyeyd@test.abc"}');

DECLARE @ExcludeProperties TABLE (Id INT,PropName VARCHAR(500))
INSERT INTO @ExcludeProperties VALUES (1,'Email');
```

--The query

```sql
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT t.Id
          ,JsonValues.[key] AS PropName
          ,JsonValues.[value] AS PropValue
    FROM @YourTable t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.Person) jsonValues
    WHERE JsonValues.[key] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT IN(SELECT excl.PropName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS FROm @ExcludeProperties excl)
)
SELECT cte.Id
      ,CONCAT('{',
      STUFF((
        SELECT CONCAT(',"',cte2.PropName,'":"',cte2.PropValue,'"')
        FROM cte cte2
        WHERE cte2.Id=cte.Id 
        FOR XML PATH('')
      ),1,1,'')
      ,'}')
FROM cte
GROUP BY cte.Id;
```

The idea in short:

First we use a CTE to create a list of all properties within your JSON as EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value). With this its easy to get rid of all the attributes, where the name is found in your exclude table.

As we are not allowed to use a column's value as the output column's alias we can build the JSON with string-methods instead of a `FOR JSON` query.

First I use a `GROUP BY` to reduce the final output to *one-row-per-Id*, and the I use a correlated sub-query to build the JSON per Id from the corresponding EAVs.

Comment: This works for me as I am sure table won't have nested JSON object.

Answer (score 9):

With corrected JSON, you can use `JSON_MODIFY()` and set the desired value to `NULL`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Id] int,[Person] varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'{"FirstName":"test", "LastName": "test", "Email": "test@test.abc"}')
,(2,'{"FirstName":"syx", "LastName": "ave", "Email": "yyeyd@test.abc"}')

Select A.ID 
      ,NewValue = JSON_MODIFY([Person],'$.Email',null)
 From  @YourTable A
```

**Returns**

```
ID  NewValue
1   {"FirstName":"test", "LastName": "test"}
2   {"FirstName":"syx", "LastName": "ave"}
```

Comment: Thanks John. but JSON_MODIFY function requires string literal as second parameter it won't accept column name from second table if I join two tables.

Comment: @Anil In 2017 it does.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c161fbee6fbd68909e822eb5ea3d59d3  However, this is one value.  If you have multiple, you may need dynamic SQL or even a recursive CTE.

Comment: I have SQL server 2016. It expect second parameter to be literal :(

Comment: @Anil Are you opposed to dynamic SQL ?

Comment: Hi John, no need for dynamic SQL acutally, +1 anyway, for the good solution and for typing in the MCVE (which I copied).

Comment: @Shnugo Your solution (+1) was very similar to my initial thoughts as well.  I changed my mind when I started to consider Nested JSON.   That reconstruction could get ugly  :) .

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Oh, that's true... That might get very ugly... ;)